# How to enable reactivity in a third party component with Slots. Vue3 & Quasar v2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I wonder if there is a way to enable reactivity in default slot at *QTooltip* component https://quasar.dev/vue-components/tooltip#qtooltip-api

The problem is that *QTooltip* content keeps its initial value and doesn't change if the prop named *'nombrePintura'* changes.

Here is the relevant code:

```js
<template>
  <div :class="{ [`box-color-container-${platform}`] : true }">
    <div :class="{ [`box-color-${platform}`] : true, 'box-color--active': pinturaActiva }"
         class="box-color"
         :style="[{ 'backgroundColor': colorHex }]"
         @click="emitSelectedColor">
    </div>
    <q-tooltip anchor="center left"
               self="center right"
               :offset="[10, 10]"
               class="text-body2 box-color-tooltip"
               :style="[{'backgroundColor': colorHex}]" v-if="platform === 'desktop'">

       <!-- This content does not update if 'nombrePintura' changes. I'd like this to be updated each time 'nombrePintura' updates. -->
      <strong class="pinturaName">{{ nombrePintura }}</strong>
    </q-tooltip>
    <span v-if="platform === 'mobile'">{{ nombrePintura }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  emits: ['onNewPaint'],
  name: 'PaintBoxColor',
  props: {
    platform: {
      type: String as PropType<'mobile' | 'desktop'>,
      required: true
    },
    nombrePintura: { // This prop changes.
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    colorHex: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    pinturaActiva: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  setup (props, ctx) {
    function emitSelectedColor () { ctx.emit('onNewPaint', props.colorHex) }
    return {
      emitSelectedColor
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

How can I update the content of q-tooltip each time prop *'nombrePintura'* changes?

Comment: I consider that your code should work in newer versions of Vue and Quasar,  because the reactivity has been improved. Is it currently working?